# Unable to replace multiple occurrence of special symbol in a string

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "D&I - Product Deployment & Integration";
str .replace("&", "&amp;")
```

This returns me only

```
"D&amp;I - Product Deployment & Integration"
```

But second symbol is not getting replaced with "&amp"

Comment: You need a regex for global replacements `str.replace(/\&/g, "&amp;")`

Comment: Thanks a lot this works